# Fetch all specific results from a table, and store them into a array

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello, I am not sure if it's been asked already, but I've been googling for 20 minutes now, could not find a relevant answer.**

I am trying to fetch ALL thread_id's in my table, and then store them into a array named $ids[]

And then make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tid = $ids[]
```

Basically, I want to fetch ALL of the posts, that their tid column is one of these that in the array.

How do I do this?

***I am using PDO by the way.***

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2 , 3 , 4 , 1' ORDER BY pid ASC LIMIT 10' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bronified\index.php:77 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bronified\index.php(77): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bronified\index.php on line 77

```
                <?php
                $test = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 10");
                $test->execute();

                while ($row = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo'<li><a href="#st-'.$row['tid'].'-'.$row['fid'].'">'. $row['subject'].'</a></li>';
                }   
                $get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC LIMIT 10");
                $get->execute();                    
                $array = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
                $test = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_threads ORDER BY replies DESC");
                $test->execute();

                $fetch = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts WHERE replyto = 0 AND tid IN :ids ORDER BY pid ASC LIMIT 10");
                $new->execute(array(":ids" => implode(" , ",$array)));

                while ($row = $new->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    echo 
                    '
                        <div id="st-'.$row['tid'].'-'.$row['fid'].'">
                            <h4>'.$row['subject'].'</h4>
                            <p>
                                '.$row['message'].'
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Where is the array coming from? Mysql or a PHP script?

Comment: Well in your new code, $array is undefined.

Comment: Sorry , added the full code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using IN and implode

```
$idsStr = implode(',', $tids);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tid IN ($idsStr)";
```

Edit: Assuming you know these ids are ints, and you're not using any other prepared statement features in it, this way is easier than making it a prepared statement. If you really want to make it a prepared statement then:

```
$idsStr = "";
foreach($tids AS $id){
    $idsStr .= "?, ";
}
$idsStr = trim($idsStr, ', ');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tid IN ($idsStr)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach($tids AS $k=>$id){
    $sth->bindParam($k, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

Edit2: It sounds like you just need to join. You said you want to select all the thread ids from a table:

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN threads ON threads.thread_id = posts.thread_id
```

Comment: How do I insert all results into the array?

Comment: Upon re-reading it sounds like you just need to learn how to do a join - if you want to select all the posts that have a thread_id, just do an INNER JOIN to threads. Do you even have posts that don't have a thread_id?

Comment: What I need is, I am building an array of thread ids, and then sending a query to select ALL posts that holds any of the thread id's in my array. please check my edit, with the error and code.

Comment: It sounds like you may not realise that an array is what is created when you build a recordset.

Comment: First part of question was, how to fetch all results from a specific column into an array.

Comment: I cant understand how do I fetch a specific column without changing * to the column name, can you provide a little example of that function, fetching a specific column 'tid' ?

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? Because it tells you: To return an array consisting of all values of a single column from the result set, specify PDO::FETCH_COLUMN. You can specify which column you want with the column-index parameter.

Comment: So columns are diplsayed from left to right, correct? the most left column will be 0, and so on, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Once again - did you read the example? It's very clear. Unless you think apple and watermelon are colors.

Comment: Did you read my question mate? I asked if the '0' on PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0, is the column number, in other words, how do I find out the column number?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31740/discussion-between-jony-kale-and-jessica)

Comment: By reading the documentation. If you don't speak English very well it's in other languages.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. array(0) { }

Comment: I have no idea what code you're running, what your data is, so no idea why it returns nothing.

Comment: You're trying to fetch the data after you already fetched it. Remove your while loop.

Comment: Okay mate, thank you. This has been fixed, though getting the same error with the second part of the code (See the edited code)

Comment: You still have $array undefined, you have too much code, you need to use a join. I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tid IN ".implode(" , ",$ids);
```

implodes transforms your PHP array into a string containing IDs separated by commas.
All you need is exec the query.

Answer (score 0):

fetch_array -- Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row  Key->Value with MYSQLI_BOTH

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$ids = implode(',',$row['id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tid IN ($ids)"
```